# Is there a way to backup all my azure services datas

Tags: azure, azure-devops, backup

I have create an "Azure DevOps organization" in Azure portal.

I am using this service to store my source code (git repositories).

I am wondering something: What happens if i accidentally delete my azure devops organization in Azure portal ? My account may be hacked too. Are there automatic backups in azure ? This question also applies to all virtual machines and every resource type on azure.

Is there a way to download all my azure data in a single tar file ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Azure DevOps side, after you delete your organization, it's disabled but available for 28 days. If you change your mind during this time, you can recover your organization. After 28 days, your organization and data are permanently deleted.

**Prerequisites**

- An organization deleted within the last 28 days.
- Organization Owner permissions to restore your organization.

**Recover organization**

1. Sign in to your [Visual Studio profile](https://app.vsaex.visualstudio.com/profile/view).
2. On your profile page, go to the lower *Organizations Pending Deletion* section, and then select **Restore**.

More details you can refer to the documentation below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/recover-your-organization?view=azure-devops

[image]

Comment: And how should i do the same operation for deleted virtual machines or storage items ? Thanks

Comment: You may check this topic: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-overview.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible to backup Azure DevOps resources into single tar file or even actually multiple in fairly easy way.

In terms of security I would recommend you this [doc site - Data protection overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/data-protection?view=azure-devops)

So your data are redundant

> To protect data in the case of hardware or service failures, Microsoft Azure storage geo-replicates customer data between two regions in the same geography; for instance, between North and West Europe or between North and South United States (except Brazil). For Azure blobs, customer data is replicated three times within a single region and is replicated asynchronously to a second region in the same geography. As such, Azure always maintains the equivalent of six copies of your data. This enables us to failover to a separate region if there's a major outage or disaster while also providing local redundancy for hardware failures within a region. For Azure SQL database storage, daily backups are maintained offsite if there's a regional disaster.

And in terms of malicious attack or accdiental deletion:

> To protect against accidental deletion of data, either by our customers or by our operation team, we also take point-in-time backups of both the Azure blob and the SQL databases. Our approach to these backups varies based on the storage type. For blobs, we have a separate copy of all blobs and regularly append new changes to each storage account. Since this data is immutable, we don't need to rewrite any existing storage as part of our backup procedures. SQL Azure, on the other hand, handles backups as a standard part of their service, which we rely on. In both cases, these backups are also replicated in a paired region to ensure we can recover from a regional outage.
>
> Also, we perform a "soft delete" for organization deletion operations, which lets us recover entire organizations for up to 28 days after deletion.

So all it looks that it is actually done by purpose. There is no way to backup it manually but plenty of aspects are already taken into account on design/architecture level.

Comment: Do you know how i should do to ask for a backup restore ? I do not need that for instance but i want to know what to do in case of problem. Thanks